# Gallery pagination: next/prev button loop same page items (views_navigation)

Tags: views, navigation

Hope someone has resolved this:

**Scenario:**
I'm on a gallery (of 3) with several pages, when clicking on any image a page opens with a bigger version of that image.

http://example.com/gallery/bol-dor-mirabaud-2013-18?position=18&list=tgC1oEBhnrxlk2VVDsHkgtUdKBxNwQ7ZbidEqXmpxVc

I can navigate by clicking on Next which will continuously load in order all images in that gallery even if they are in other pages (pagination).

**Problem:**
If I click on a page, lets say  page 2: http://example.com/gallery/611?page=2
and the click on the image will do the same as described before but when clicking on prev/next will loop only between images on that page.

How I get it to work like the default page? noticed the list parameter is always changing after page load and maybe there's a way to set that to a fix variable like gallery id?

I'm using drupal 7.41 /PHP 5.4.39 / views_navigation 7.x-1.2-beta2

Thanks